# Problem cloning gitolite on Ubuntu

Tags: git, github, gitolite

I installed gitolite on a Ubuntu10.04 machine and created a repository A. My team remotely checked in code into that branch. Now I want to clone this repository on the same Ubuntu machine. How I can do it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the purpose of this new clone? Do you need gitolite branch management on this clone?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the filesystem based clone (vs. ssh, git or http protocols) to clone the repo.

Something like this should work while you're in the directory you want to clone to:

`git clone /path/to/repo`